# Why the result webservice gives a json[{"Cant_38":"2.00","Cant_40": "9.50","Cant_42":"2.00"}] but Android receives all "0"

Tags: php, android, response

That data is received in a function with HttpURLConnection object  as con

```
`    
JSONObject json=null;
<br>
if (con==null){
  return null;
}
try
{
  OutputStream 
  os=con.getOutputStream();
  BufferedWriter bw=new 
  BufferedWriter(new 
  OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
  if(this.params!=null) {
    bw.write(this.params);
  }
 bw.flush();
 bw.close();
 os.close();

 int 
responseCode=con.getResponseCode();



if (responseCode==con.HTTP_OK)
 {

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer response=new 
 StringBuffer();
 String line;
 while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                    
 //Lod.v("received: ",line) show all 0  ##***<--- Here
                   
  response.append(line);
  if(response.toString().contains("failed")){Log.e("Error de conexión:" ,response.toString());}
  }
    
br.close();
//............. more code ....
json = new JSONObject(response.toString());
} 
  `
```

##***Here
[{"Cant_38":".00","Cant_40":".00","Cant_42":".00}]

I've tried to change php codification by adding JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE to echo json_encode($res).
echo json_encode($res,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Api web is ok [{"Cant_38":"2.00","Cant_40": "9.50","Cant_42":"2.00"}]

Thinking about it, perhaps the problem is HttpURLConnection object. Do you know?

Comment: Sorry is my first time asking with code

Comment: I dont understand why people gets negative feedback

Answer (score 0):

These lines should be added before you attempt to get the output stream:

```
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setDoInput(true);
```

Comment: Yes i did it. This isn't the problem. In con object i have it.  `          URL u = new URL(urltext);
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();

            httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpConn.setConnectTimeout(20000);
            httpConn.setReadTimeout(20000);
            httpConn.setDoInput(true);
            httpConn.setDoOutput(true);

            return httpConn;`

Answer (score 0):

All right
Then was a string parameter sended with single quotes 'value' among others

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).